# Why is my image not scaling to its div when height is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to create a simple fluid image viewer: two arrows hugging variable width central images. The images would be scaled according to a fixed height that is a percentage of the viewport.

However when I set my image height to 100% via css it stretches its div past its max height.
Heres a codepen link to show you what I mean: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjrhk/?editors=000

I know I need to have defined a height all the way up the heirarchy, which I think I've done, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I know this is a common question but seems to be a different problem with each person...

Comment: Both the width and the hight can't be a percentage. It's one or the other

Comment: When I remove the width:100% from the relevant places it still doesn't scale, could you expand a little?
Also, is there no way in say, setting the parent div to 80% width and having the height stretch to fit its content?